# how to implement timers similar to timers in dot connecting game in mytalking tom in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, timer

I would like to know how to implement timers that are similar to those of timers in my talking tom dot connecting game. It would be great if you could help me out. I am new to this field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [CountDownTimers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). 
And how you would use it is as follows:

```
new CountDownTimer(TotalTime, intervalJump) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     //update your UI here to reflect the time left (represented 
     //in millis until finished
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     //the countdown is finished
 }
 }.start();
```

Comment: how to implement that in xml file :/

Comment: A countdown timer isn't a UI aspect, it is a thread which runs in the background and counts down. The UI aspect is entirely dependent on your design choice. You could for example use 100 Images that represent different stages of the load bar in an imageView, and change the background of the imageView based on the countDownTimer progress (Though this is the bad way of doing it).